# X-cache hit after Azure CDN Purge

Tags: azure, caching, azure-blob-storage, azure-cdn

I'm using Azure CDN to retrieve files from Azure blob storage.
After updating a file in my storage, checking the file with storage explorer, and purging the CDN (purge all), I try to refresh the plain-file within my browser.

In the response I see `x-cache: HIT`, which indicates that it's still loaded from the CDN cache. How is this possible after purging?

I tried purging using the Azure Portal as well as `Unpublish-AzureRmCdnEndpointContent` using powershell.

Answer (score 0):

You may need some time to wait for purging requests. Also, you must note that there still are downstream caches even you **purging all**.

> Note that purging only clears the cached content **on the CDN edge
>   servers**. Any downstream caches, such as proxy servers and local
>   browser caches, may still hold a cached copy of the file. It's
>   important to remember this when you set a file's time-to-live. You can
>   force a downstream client to request the latest version of your file
>   by giving it a unique name every time you update it, or by taking
>   advantage of [query string caching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-query-string).

You can get more details from [Purge an Azure CDN endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-purge-endpoint)

Comment: Is there any update in your side? Is this reply helpful?

Comment: It turned out to be an url rewrite problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45047188/azure-cdn-purge-not-refreshing-cached-content