# Azure CDN purge not working due to local browser cache with long TTL / Cache - how to force refresh global rule?

Tags: azure, caching, cdn, azure-cdn

I encounter the problem reported in [X-cache hit after Azure CDN Purge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52096287/x-cache-hit-after-azure-cdn-purge) , that if I set a long Always Cache expiration / TTL of for example 1 year, the local browser will not fetch new content from the Azure CDN EVEN one does a manual Azure CDN purge, because the browser just takes the local cache.

In our web setup, we would like the Azure CDN to cache everthing UNTIL our next deployment, thats why we set a long global "Always Cache expiration" of 1 year. We assumed that the a manual CDN purge will force the browser to refresh, but it didnt because of the local browser cache where the TTL 1 year is locked. Now users still get old apps after our deployments.

Can this be solved with additional directives?

When we set `"Last-Modified" : "<date>"` as global directive after each deployment we get an error. ETag does not seem to be supported by standard MS CDN plan.

```
{"ErrorMessage":"Invalid RulesEngineConfig: (Header \"Last-Modified\" is not allowed to be modified by the rules engine)."}
```

What are the exact rule settings in Azure CDN to solve this use case and control that the browser gets new content only after we deployed?

Answer (score 0):

The browser is doing what you instructed it to do given the caching rules.

What you could do is configure the assets with unique filenames or a cache fingerprint and a very long cache TTL. But the HTML page with a shorter TTL. So when you update assets, users will get a fresh HTML page and pull the latest assets.